# How would C++ hardware destructive & constructive interference size work with the mandated declaration order?

Tags: c++, c++17, memory-layout, c++23

For reference, the interference size is part of C++17, [P0154R1](https://wg21.link/P0154R1), and mandated declaration order is proposed for C++23, [P1847R4](http://wg21.link/P1847R4).

As far as I understand...

- The first proposal requires the compiler to move alignas-ed member variables closer together / farther away.
- The second proposal would require the compiler to lay out member variables in order of declaration in the class.

Seems to me the 2nd proposal takes the punch out of the first. `hardware_destructive_interference_size` would necessarily require leaving unused memory between the two member variables, with no option to fill it with other members. `hardware_constructive_interference_size` would be reduced to a warning saying "can't do it, try reordering the member variables yourself".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[P0154](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0154r1.html) makes no changes to how member variables are laid out. It merely exposes some `constexpr` variables, which you can use to adjust the alignment of member variables through `alignas`. But `alignas` doesn't gain any special properties.

That is, these two structs have the same layout, if `hardware_destructive_interference_size` is 64:

```
struct one
{
  alignas(hardware_destructive_interference_size) int member1;
  alignas(hardware_destructive_interference_size) int member2;
};

struct two
{
  alignas(64) int member1;
  alignas(64) int member2;
};
```

[P1847](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p1847r4.pdf) doesn't actually change any behavior. It removes a degree of freedom that was previously available to compilers when laying out the order of members in a class. This removal doesn't change any compiler's behavior because... no compilers took advantage of this degree of freedom. That's *why* the committee is removing it; nobody did anything with it.

Also, said degree of freedom is the ability to layout members with different access classes (`public`/`private`). The layout of members *within* an access class has been declaration order since (at least) C++11.

So these two changes have nothing to do with one another.

Comment: So all the compilers are free to do is move either the first or second variable to the next cache line? That's precious little.

Comment: @UriRaz: You misunderstand. If you `alignas` a member variable, the compiler is *required* to provide that alignment for that member variable. Period (unless the compiler doesn't support an alignment that big). If your alignment happens to map to a cache line, then you ensure that they're on separate cache lines. But the compiler is simply doing what you told it to do.

Comment: P0154 is not a magical salve that tells the compiler to move stuff around to different cache lines. It's a tool that allows the *user* to tell the compiler how to arrange members so that they can be on different cache lines.